# How can I check if email exists in the database or not?

Tags: php, validation, pdo, mariadb

This is my `init.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
'mysql' => array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'db' => 'mostwanted'
),
'remember' => array(
    'cookie_name' => 'hash',
    'cookie_expiry' => 604800
),
'session' => array(
    'session_name' => 'user',
    'token_name' => 'token'
)
);

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
require_once 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
});

require_once 'functions/sanitize.php';
```

And this is my `DB.php`

```
class DB {

private static $_instance = null;

private $_pdo, 
        $_query, 
        $_error = false, 
        $_results, 
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {

    try {

        $this->_pdo = new PDO(
            'mysql:host=' . 
            Config::get('mysql/host') . 
            ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), 
            Config::get('mysql/username'), 
            Config::get('mysql/password'));

    } catch(PDOException $e) {

        die($e->getMessage());

    }

}

public static function getInstance() {

    if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {

        self::$_instance = new DB();

    }

    return self::$_instance;

}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {

        $x = 1;

        if(count($params)) {

            foreach($params as $param) {

                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;

            }

        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {

            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount(); 

        }

        else {

            $this->_error = true;

        }

    }

    return $this;

}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {

    if(count($where) === 3) {

        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {

            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {

                return $this;

            }

        }
    }
    return false;
}


public function get($table, $where) {

    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);

}

public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {

    $keys = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $field) {

        $values .= "?";

        if($x < count($fields)) {

            $values .= ', ';

        }

        $x++;


        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`" . implode('`,`', $keys) . "`) VALUES      ({$values})";

        if($this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {

            return true;

        }

        echo $sql;

    }

    return false;

}

public function update($table, $id, $fields) {

    $set = '';
    $x = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {

        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {

            $set .= ', ';

        }

        $x++;

    }

    $sql = "UPDATE {$table} SET {$set} WHERE user_id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

public function delete($table, $where) {

    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);

}

public function results() {

    return $this->_results;

}

public function first() {

    return $this->results()[0];

}

public function error() {

    return $this->_error;

}

public function count() {

    return $this->_count;

}

}
```

I'm not sure whether I should change __construct() to a public function or not to call it into my `register.php`, where I'm trying to find whether the email entered in the space is in the database or not.

```
$query = DB::__construct()->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = ?" );
$query->bindValue( 1, $email );
$query->execute();

if( $query->rowCount() > 0 )  # If rows are found for query
{
echo "Email has already been registered";
}
else
{
echo "Email has not been registered before";
}
```

I will get "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Non-static method DB::__construct() cannot be called statically in C:\xampp\htdocs\MostWanted\register.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\MostWanted\register.php on line 4" when I type in an email.

Comment: so the code does nt work? what part?

Comment: In the register.php. I'm pretty sure the connection to DB is made but I have  no idea how to use that connection to access the email column without changing the private function to a public one.

Answer (score 0):

A private constructor is a sign that class is implemented as a Singleton pattern (very common in classes used for database access).

Look for another public method, probably something like "instance()", "getInstance()", "getConnection"...